# apply which.max to second, third, etc. highest value

Tags: r

I have a vector:

`x<-rnorm(100)`,

I would like to create a vector that stores the position of the first, second, third...100th highest value in X.

For example if `x=4,9,2,0,10,11` then the desired vector would be `6,5,2,1,3,4` is there a function for doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using `order`

```
> order(x, decreasing =TRUE)
[1] 6 5 2 1 3 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
> order(-x)
[1] 6 5 2 1 3 4
```